# What metrics are available on malware?

Tags: antimalware

All the main AV have a risk rating or severity level, how do they determine what is "low","high",etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each company will use a different scale, but they all will likely be the result of a weighted score considering:

- if it escalates itself
- the damage it causes
- if it disrupts communication
- how hard it is to block/remove
- how easy it is to get infected
- how it gets passed on to other machines

Here is a similar scale:
http://reviews.cnet.com/4520-6600_7-6274750-1.html

Symantec rates malware based on reputation and behavior classification and doesn't use a 'low-high' scale anymore.

Comment: Thank you, behavior classification sounds interesting, I'll have to check that out.